# Building OpenCV3.1.0 error: use of undeclared identifier 'selectROI'

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, build, roi

Building OpenCV 3.1.0 from Github.
Which fails when it comes to compiling the **tutorial example: features2D**.

First, it complaint it did not find `#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>     //for ROI`

So, I added `video`: `#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>     //for ROI`

Solved the finding problem.

Then complaint about `selectROI`: `cv::Rect2d uBox = selectROI(video_name, frame);`

From terminal:

```
[ 98%] Built target tutorial_objectDetection
[ 98%] Built target tutorial_objectDetection2
[ 98%] Building CXX object samples/cpp/CMakeFiles/tutorial_planar_tracking.dir/tutorial_code/features2D/AKAZE_tracking/planar_tracking.cpp.o
/GitHub/opencv/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/features2D/AKAZE_tracking/planar_tracking.cpp:174:27: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'selectROI'
        cv::Rect2d uBox = selectROI(video_name, frame);
                          ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [samples/cpp/CMakeFiles/tutorial_planar_tracking.dir/tutorial_code/features2D/AKAZE_tracking/planar_tracking.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [samples/cpp/CMakeFiles/tutorial_planar_tracking.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?

note: I would delete it all together, but it would be nice if I had it.

And as you can see, fails on 98% -_-

Comment: this problem will be solved soon (keep [offical issue](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6209#issuecomment-192468801). for now you can skip this file to complate build process

Comment: Thanks @sturkmen, thats what I did.

Comment: @sturkmen I got the same error but I do not know how to "skip this file"? Can you please explain?

Comment: @araknafobia if I may.. you just delete features2D file. Then regenerate cmake. Hope it helps.

Comment: you can edit the file like [here](https://github.com/sturkmen72/opencv/blob/beeef1eaab6b3c547047d227b901d2bb2deffbd4/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/features2D/AKAZE_tracking/planar_tracking.cpp) to skip it